# Characteristic classes of unit sphere bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\xi:E\to M$ a real vector bundle over $M$. Suppose we fix a metric $g$ on $E$ so that we can define the unit sphere bundle $S(E)\to M$.

How are the characteristic classes of the tangent bundle $TS(E)$ related to the characteristic classes of the vector bundle $\xi$? For example, can we compute $w_2(\xi)$ and $p_1(\xi)$ in terms of the characteristic classes of $TS(E)$?

I think the choice of metric on $E$ is irrelevant here since the space of metrics in contractible. Maybe we could use the Leray-Hirsch theorem?

Comment: How are the characteristic classes of the sphere bundle defined?

Comment: $S(E)$ is a smooth manifold (which is compact if $M$ is compact), so the characteristic classes of the tangent bundle $TS(E)$ are defined in the usual way.

Comment: The tangent bundle to the sphere bundle splits as the Whitney sum of the vertical tangent bundle and the pullback of the tangent bundle $TM$ to $S(E)$.

Comment: Could you please explain how the decomposition you mention helps us calculate the characteristic classes of $\xi$? My question is how to determine the characteristic classes of $\xi$, given that the characteristic classes of $TS(E)$ are known.

Comment: You use the product formula for characteristic classes of a direct sum. You might need to do some work to figure out some characteristic classes of the vertical tangent bundle, but maybe you can get away without that knowledge.